# How do I replace all occurances of a string with a large amount of text?

Tags: replace

I modifying a gcode file with custom toolswap codee, and I need to replace every instance of "T0" (`^T0$`) with a large amount of text (19 lines), which is stored in a separate file. How can I do so quickly?

There are about 100 instances that need replacement, and I can see the need to do more in the future, so I need something that does it all at once.

I tried defining a macro with `q` to replace one instance, hoping to run it a certain number of times, but I could only run the macro once. The macro deleted the line, and then read (`:r`) from the other file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that work for you?

```
:%s/^T0$/\=readfile('filename')/g
```

It will replace every occurence of `T0` with the content of `filename`.

Comment: Thanks! That did exactly what I needed. I wasn't familiar with this type of syntax. Would you know where it is documented?

Comment: `=` is a register (a special one called the "expression register"). To look up help for registers you precede them with `@`. So `:h @=`. For the specific context of expression register use in the substitution command there's `:h sub-replace-expression` aka `:h s:\=`.